# calculation in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a simple UK tax calculation, for example, my pay (z) - personal allowance(x) and then times tax rate band ie 20% (y) and putting the answer in cell A8 using visual basic in excel 2013, sorry I'm a  beginner to this. I can do this using the macro recorder, however, I want it to be my own code

```
Sub test()
    Dim x, y, z As Integer

    x = 10000
    y = 20
    z = Range("B1").Value
    Range("A8") = [z] - [x] * [y]
 End Sub
```

Comment: [Can someone help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ist not really a question. What is your problem with the code you posted?

Comment: In the above example is my code for calculations that I have done but it is not returning the answer that is correct, is there something I have done that is incorrect,

 I declared the 3 variables 

x (personal allowance) = 10000
y(tax rate) = 20%
z (my pay) = cell b1

so the calculation would go "my pay" minus "personal allowance" times "Tax Rate" and the answer would be put in cell A8 but I have tried playing with the code above and cant get the result.

Comment: You declared z as integer and x,y as variant. And what would be the correct answer according to your opinion? And then ask yoursel, why? How do you calculate a percentage like 20%? Certainly not by multiplying with 20.

Comment: @Storax I think criticizing the OP for "Can someone help" is not appropriate here.  They have provided the required elements of a OK (albeit basic) Q, they just happened to tack those words on the end.  And you answered it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that aren't quite right here.
You need to take the difference before multiplying, so add () around the subtraction. 
And 20% = 0.2, so

y = 0.2

Range("A8") = (z - x) * y

I don't use VBA, so your results may vary.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Double, y As Double, z As Double

    x = 10000
    y = 0.2
    z = Range("B1").Value
    Range("A8") = (z - x) * y

End Sub
```